# Identifying peaks at every cluster

Tags: algorithms, graphs, python

I have a data set showing different clusters of data points and was attempting to find a way to get the peak of at every cluster. Comparing the moving average between a set of points does not work as the y values fluctuate up and down as x increases.

[image]

Comment: What, for the scope of this question, is a *peak*? And what is the problem in *identifying peaks*? What is your answerable CS question?

Comment: What is your question?  If you are looking for an algorithm to solve some task, often a good format is to specify the input to the algorithm and the desired output (what criteria does the output have to satisfy, to count as a correct output?).  Please define all terms -- what is a peak, what is a cluster, what do you mean by comparing moving averages?  I encourage you to [edit] your question to clarify what you are asking.